# Maclaurin series of a function with a nasty integral

Tags: calculus, integration, taylor-expansion

The instructions to the section are: Find the maclaurin series for each of the following functions:

The 'function' in question is below

$$\int_0^u \frac{\sin(x) dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

I first looked at

$$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\cdots$$

and using the binomial series on the denominator I get

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=(1-x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}= 1+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{3x^2}{8}+\cdots$$

But still, I cannot seem to relate the above two expansions to $\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$.  Any ideas about how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\sin(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$ for any $x$ and 
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{4^n}x^{2n} $$
for any $x$ such that $|x|<1$. It follows that
$$ \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\sum_{r\geq 0}(-1)^r x^{2r+1}\sum_{n=0}^{r}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}(-1)^{n}}{4^n(2r-2n+1)!} $$
and 
$$ \int_{0}^{u}\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx = \sum_{r\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^r u^{2r+2}}{2r+1}\sum_{n=0}^{r}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}(-1)^n}{4^n(2r-2n+1)!}$$
for any $|u|<1$.

Comment: The inner sum can be reduced :)

Comment: @OlivierOloa: really? It is $\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$, not $\frac{\arcsin x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$.

Comment: Oops...! thanks! I've to delete my answer!